# coffeescript install

Tags: macos, shell, coffeescript, installation

I can't install CoffeeScript on my Macbook. The same commands works just fine on my iMac.

```
$ surganov:~ surganov$ sudo npm install coffee-script -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/cake -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
coffee-script@1.3.3 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script

$ surganov:~ surganov$ coffee
-bash: coffee: command not found
```

Answer (score 15):

If you want to access coffescript binary globally, you need to install it so:

```
npm install -g coffee-script
```

And then add the installation directory to your `PATH`. Good way to automate this is to use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

Comment: Problem is CoffeeScript installing by default to _/usr/local/share/npm/lib/_ for some reason, but have to be installed to /usr/local/bin/coffee

Comment: Simply add a path as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988677/difficulty-installing-node-js-and-coffeescript-in-mac-osx

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. When install with '-g', npm install to /usr/local/share/npm so you can't use, eg 'coffee' command. You can check where npm install node_modules with:

```
npm prefix -g
```

If it's not /usr/local then you can use `npm config edit` to edit prefix. It'll create a .npmrc file in your root (if it's not there). Otherwise, open the file with text editor and change the prefix. More info here: [npm config](https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html)

Comment: Thank you! Although for me running 'npm prefix' just printed my current location, and running 'npm config edit' gave me a bunch of erros. To set the path I ran: 'npm config set prefix /usr/local' and to confirm I ran 'npm config list'

Answer (score 0):

- Locate your coffeescript bin directory (by typing locate coffee)
- Edit your ~/.profile file and add:
  export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin::$PATH
  (or whereever your coffee-script/bin is located)
- Save the profile file
- type source ~./profile (only this time) to load the new path
- now you have the coffee command