# Global NPM Modules Don't Work on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: node.js, osx-mountain-lion, npm, gruntjs, forever

I have a good install of

Node@v0.8.14 and NPM@1.1.65 on OS X 10.8.2 for local development.

Everything works as expected except for packages that I try to install with the `-g` flag for global, like grunt or forever, aren't found as terminal commands.

I have tried adding some paths but nothing's worked so far...

Here's my standard `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share:/usr/local/share/npm:/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/:.npm
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: do you get any errors in the terminal? did you try `sudo npm install ...` ?

Comment: try `cd /usr/local/bin; ls` do you see your installed node_modules here?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have node v0.8.12 on Mountain Lion. Installing express globally. 'express' command is not found. Perhaps the install paths have changed in a recent npm version?

Comment: To fix I added express bin folder to the $PATH variable in the /etc/launchd.conf (you may have to create this file). Might just be a workaround. See http://overwatering.org/blog/2012/08/setting-path-osx-mountain-lion/ for help.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue - I resolved it by installing n globally

```
npm install -g n
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem as well. You need to check your npm prefix, change it to /usr/local if it's not. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212875/coffeescript-install/14602913#14602913).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was installing modules right into my user folder, like:

```
cd ~
npm install whatever
```

This is not a pretty solution as soon my user folder now have a node_modules directory, but I'm tired to try make things right.

Answer (score -2):

install NPM modules with sudo command,

like this

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why you don't want to be doing this, namely it potentially opens up your machine to all sorts of risks.  NPM is designed to not require sudo.  It may be acting buggy for your right now, but consider one of the other options such as changing permissions or the prefix location of global installs.