# Difficulty installing Node.js and CoffeeScript in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, node.js, coffeescript, npm

I'm having some difficulty installing Node and Coffeescript. I have installed node using homebrew and then I have successfully installed NPM. I have tried to install Coffeescript from NPM and it appears to have worked but then I cannot run coffee

```
localserver:Documents x$ sudo npm -g install coffee-script
Password:
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee-script
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/coffee -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/cake -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake
coffee-script@1.4.0 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script
localserver:Documents x$ coffee
-bash: coffee: command not found
localserver:Documents x$
```

Is there some path environment variable that I need to set for this? Even if I navigate to `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee` I cannot run it from here.

Comment: Did you try running the following command: `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee`?

Comment: That actually works. I'm just getting my head round unix - why would it work entering the full path but not being in that place and running it from here?

Comment: Because if you just type `coffee`, it will look for the `coffee` script in your PATH settings. If you just type the name of the script (with its path), it will execute it. If you're in the path of the script, you need to type `./coffee` (`.` being current directory).

Comment: never ever use sudo for node package manager as recommended in the documentation: http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm.
if you already used sudo, you should reorganize your permissions of installed global modules that sudo isnt nessesary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like npm doesn't add coffee's directory to the PATH. You can fix it with the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/:$PATH
```

I'm quite sure there must be a better way though. But I don't know enough OSX to answer.

If you want this change to be permanent, add the line to your `~/.profile` file.

Comment: I guess it is an OSX thing and could be the reason why it didn't set it but I don't actually have a `~/.profile` file. If I `vi ~/.profile/'` it creates a new file.

Comment: @MrWilde then create it. Looks like OSX picks up this file if it exists.

Comment: Very helpful although not ideal, this worked for my "less" problems as well. So essential you are just prepending coffee to your path?

Comment: You may have a .bash_profile rather than a .profile. If you do "echo $SHELL" and the result is "/bin/bash", you should use .bash_profile. See http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/6.3/postlfs/profile.html

Answer (score 6):

On Mac OS X, `.bashrc` is the best place to specify your $PATH ([bashrc vs bash_profile](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html)).

You want to add a path that will work for all (globally installed) Node modules, which would be `/usr/local/share/npm/bin`. To do that, you can type the following into your shell (where ^D means pressing Control-D to end the input).

```
cat >> ~/.bashrc

export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:${PATH}"
^D
```

Comment: Another good place to add paths on OS X is /etc/paths.d.  This will ensure they're available to all users on the machine. You can either add the paths to /etc/paths or drop a file in /etc/paths.d called "node" or "npm" or whatever. The contents of the file should be the paths you want to add, one per line.